# How To get html code inside div with an ID with SimpleHTMLDom PHP?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

This is simple html demo code where i want to fetch html content between div with id first.

```
<div id="first">
   <div id="second">second</div>
   <div class="third">Third</div>
   <h1>Fourth</h1>
</div>
```

So output of it will be like

```
<div id="second">second</div>
<div class="third">Third</div>
<h1>Fourth</h1>
```

I tried many things but it didn't work such as :

```
$dom->find('div[id="first"]')->innertext;


$var = (string)$dom->find('div[id="first"]');
```

So, how to extract html code within div?

Comment: have you tried `->plaintext` instead of `->innertext`

Comment: @SmartCoder No, That's not working either. It prints only whitepace.

Comment: Have you tried `DOMDocument`?

Comment: No, i never heard of it, Can you write some demo?

Answer (score 2):

`find()` method returns an array of elements. You probably want the `innertext` of the first element like this:

```
$result = $dom->find('div[id="first"]');
print ($result[0]->innertext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Here we are using `simplexml_load_string` , querying with `XPath`.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/893605)

```
<?php

$dom=simplexml_load_string($your_html_source_string);
$results=$dom->xpath('//div[@id="first"]/*');
$innerHtml="";
foreach($results as $result)
{
    $innerHtml.=$result->saveXML();
}
echo $innerHtml;
```

Comment: Hey,Thanks for reply.
I am trying to scrap description from http://www.shopclues.com/apple-iphone-6-gold-32gb-125551253.html.
Product description html code is inside "product_description" ID.

I am using simple_HTML_dom to parse html and it returns the object of child and nodes.
So i can not pass html source inside simplexml_load_string() function which you provided.

So can you tell me what's the alternative of that?

Comment: @ravi For that you can use `simplexml_load_file`.

Comment: @ravi according to the problem mentioned above, My code is working fine.

Comment: Maybe there is error from my side.. I am not able to find it..
When i run code you suggested, it returns 500 error code.